# Correlation between two dataframes / curves

Tags: python, correlation, finance, curve, quantitative-finance

I have yield curve data for two currencies (Euro and U.S. Dollar). For each of these currencies I have 16 variables (16 maturities). I have generated, using some model, synthetic curves and I want to relate the curves of the two currencies. That is, what is the correlation between the two currencies? I am asking this question as my model should capture this correlation. For example, it wouldn't be great if a 4% euro curve is generated and at the same time a -4% level curve is generated for the dollar. How can I do this? I don't like a correlation matrix as this yields a 16x16 matrix per model (I have multiple). Any thoughts?! Could be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just build a new DataFrame out of the two other DataFrames with the Series you want and call [corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)?

It is hard to provide a exact solution (and i may not understand your problem fully), as you didn't provide any information on how the data looks or what your code looks already

```
import pandas as pd

# your code so far...

df_corr = pd.DataFrame()
df_corr['eur_curve'] = df_eur # asumming you have a df_eur with the curve and 16 "variables"
df_corr['usd_cuve'] = df_usd # asumming you have a df_usd with the curve and 16 "variables"
corr = df_corr.corr()
```